# Will legacy index template work after elasticsearch version 8 upgrade?

Tags: elasticsearch, elk

I currently working on cluster with version 7.17.7 and now I am thinking of upgrading it to version 8.x. I received an API deprecation log that Legacy index templates are deprecated in favor of composable templates. Now at the moment in my cluster I have quite a few of legacy index templates working and they are used in receiving data as well. Now if I upgrade the cluster to version 8.x will these templates still work or I have to scrap all of these templates first and configure Composable templates and then upgrade the cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`legacy templates` created in Elasticsearch 7.18 will still work in Elasticsearch 8.X, its just a deprecation warning, you can easily test it yourself by creating a legacy template on Elasticsearch 8.X and see new index created using these legacy templates working in your cluster or not.

Comment: So my legacy index templates created in 7.17 will work accordingly when upgraded to 8.x right?

Comment: @UmangPachaury yes, as suggested you should test few before trying to do migration of all